# Doctrine OneToMany not return relationships Collection

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, relationship, symfony6

I have a OneToMany relation that doesn't return items if the method stays as the return with Collection type

`Account::class`

```
.
.
#[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'account', targetEntity: Folder::class, orphanRemoval: true)]
public Collection $folders;
.
.

/**
 * @return Collection<int, Folder>
 */
public function getFolders(): Collection
{
    return $this->folders;
}
```

`Folder::class`

```
#[ORM\ManyToOne(inversedBy: 'folders')]
#[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'account_id', referencedColumnName: 'id', nullable: false)]
public ?Account $account = null;
```

`

If I change the return type from getFolders to array and call $this->folders->toArray() the data is returned.
Is this related to EAGER and LAZY? I can't understand what doctrine is doing here.

```
I thought that since it is a code generalized by symfony itself, the return with the Collection type should have the same result. Where am I getting lost?
```

Comment: You mean that if you do `$account->getFolders()` you're getting an empty `Collection` object? That's lazy loading: Doctrine does not load the `Folder` objects in the `Collection` until a method on the `Collection` object is called. Which is what you're doing by calling `$this->folders->toArray()`. The `Folder` objects in the `Collection` are also loaded if you loop over `$account->getFolders()` because php internally calls methods on the `Collection` to return the next item in the loop, so you usually don't need to manually call `->toArray()`.

Comment: But is this a `Collection` thing or is it a `Doctrine` implementation thing? I'm a layman in these deeper parts. In this case, I need to either call `->toArray()` to retrieve the entire list or iterate through the `->getFolders()` function and interact with each item retrieved by the `Collection`?

Comment: Doctrine uses an implementation of the `Collection` interface (this class  https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/827cb0c10bd0440b5e1b8ec7f5dc1fc1810f1821/lib/Doctrine/ORM/PersistentCollection.php ) as a wrapper around the `ArrayCollection` that holds your `Folder` objects. This lets it only load the `Folder` objects when they are needed to avoid unnecessary database calls.

Comment: You can use `->getFolders()` in a loop or call any of the methods from the `Collection` interface on it, any of those interactions will cause Doctrine to load the `Folder` objects into the `ArrayCollection`. Basically, use `->getFolders()` as if the `Folder` objects are already there and let Doctrine do its loading magic in the background.